# Add "other" as a input text option to dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown where i want to add an option to insert your own text, can't seem to find it in documentation on getbootstrap.com or anywhere else.

Has anyone encountered this before?

I have tried to make a select dropdown and btn dropdown. Also insert text, but i don't seem to solve it.

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':XPO.touched && XPO.invalid}">
<!--Unsure this is correct-->
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="XPO" title="">
        Name of company
        <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control" name="xpocompany" [(ngModel)]="category.status">
            <option data-tokens="company 1" [selected]="category.status ==0">company 1</option>
            <option data-tokens="Company 2" [selected]="category.status ==1">company 2</option>
            <option data-tokens="company 3" [selected]="category.status ==2">Company 3</option>     
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="XPO.touched && XPO.invalid">
            <p class="required" *ngIf="XPO.errors.required">Choose company</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like a dropdown where there's a "other" option where user can input any other company name. Perhaps a new box for "other" or directly in the dropdown. However i also want live search so another box might be the best.

Comment: i think you are looking for something like select2. If I'm not wrong it should have an option to add your extra option.

Comment: @LelioFaieta thank you. For someone that isn´t certain, could you guide me to where i find select2? It's another library and not in bootstrap correct?

Comment: have you ever heard about a wonderful tool called google? :-)

Comment: LoL @LelioFaieta please tell me more ;) (ps. found bootstrap.theme, but that didn't help me in my question. I will continue searching, just asked incase you had a quick reply so i could focus on the code instead of searching) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First edition solution:**
Had to rewrite to typescript [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fastersixth/n8me395g/)

**Final solution**, Just forgot to upload the code. Here's how I did it.

```
<div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error':xpo.touched && xpo.invalid}" *ngIf="product.xpoSelection == '1'">
<label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="XPO" title="">
Name of producer<br>
<small style="font-weight:normal;">
<i>Missing producer choose "Other" and fill field below</i></small>
</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7" *ngIf="xpo">
  <select class="form-control" title="Producer" [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" required id="xpo" name="xpo"  >
         <option selected value="base">Choose producer</option>
         <option value="other">Other</option>
         <option *ngFor="let object of xpo.XpoList" [value]="object.Name" [selected]="object.Name == selectedXpoCompany">{{object.Name}}</option>  </select>
<!--OTHER XPO-->
   <div *ngIf="selectedVal === 'other'">
       <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label" for="otherXpo" title="">
          Please enter other XPO<br>
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="otherXpo" id="otherXpo" #otherXpo="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.XPO" name="otherXpo"  />
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <br>
 </div>
</div>
```